# Need to find number of distinct values in each column in very large files

Tags: c#, memory-management, large-files, distinct-values

I am processing large files in C# (hopefully) and I need a way to determine the number of distinct values in each column of file.  I have read all the questions I can find relating to determining distinct values with C#.  The challenge is that due to the large size of some files and potential for tens of millions of distinct values in a column (and potentially hundreds of columns--all sorts of datatypes), to create lists, dictionaries, or arrays, etc. for each column--and then using techniques described in previously-answered questions--would put me in danger of hitting the 2 GB memory limitation.

Currently, I am reading/processing the files one line at a time and for each row "cleaning and sanitizing" the data, updating aggregate results, then writing each processed row in an output file which is then bulk inserted to SQL.  Performance thus far is actually pretty decent.

Since the data is ultimately landed in MS SQL, as a fallback I can use SQL to determine distinct values but I would ideally like to be able to do this before landing in SQL. Any thoughts or suggestions are appreciated.

**Update:** For each field I have created a Hash Table and added new distinct values to each.  At the end of processing, I use 
    myDistinctValues.Count
to obtain the count.  This works fine for small files but as I feared, with a large file I get

```
System.OutOfMemoryException
```

thrown.  Per a suggestion, I did try adding

```
<runtime>
    <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true"/>
</runtime>
```

to my application config but that did not help.

Comment: Wirh this strict requirements only some kind of persistent BTree comes to mind.

Comment: What 2GB memory limitation?  If compiled for AnyCPU architecture and then run on an x64 machine, you shouldn't have such a limitation.

Comment: @KevinAnderson, I'm referring to this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/joshwil/2005/08/10/bigarrayt-getting-around-the-2gb-array-size-limit/

Comment: @bamanow, that is interesting. I will research to see how to possibly use BTree in C# context.  Thank you!

Comment: gcAllowVeryLargeObjects only relates to array sizes (the sum of all object sizes in the array). Ensure your build settings are generating an x64 binary (not ANyCPU) and ensure the "prefer 32bit" setting is off. Run your app; if it really is sucking up all the memory on the machine, you're probably going to have to add more memory, or do the dedupe in SQLserver (set primary key on the column(s) to be unique)

Comment: ps; the maths in both my example and in cassandrad's answer works out the same - s/he quoted ~0.125 gig for 1 million objects and I saw 0.14gig per million unique objects (but i was counting unique occurrences too).. On my lowly 16 gig machine, non loaded, I probably could have got to 50-100 million unique strings in the set if I rebooted prior and stopped it folding proteins - if you have files that are larger than this, i think you might have a bigger problem; doesn't sound like the sort of data a lowly machine should be handling!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though my solution is not elegant and there is surely a better one out there (BTree?), I found something that worked and thought I'd share it.  I can't be the only one out there looking to determine distinct counts for fields in very large files.  That said, I don't know how well this will scale to hundreds of millions or billions of records.  At some point, with enough data, one will hit the 2GB size limit for a single array.

**What didn't work:**

- For very large files: hash table for each field populated in real time as I iterate through the file, then use hashtable.count.  The collective size of the hash tables causes SystemOutOfMemoryException before reaching the end of the file.
- Importing data to SQL then using SQL on each column to determine distinct count.  It takes *WAY* too long.

**What did work:**

- For the large files with tens of millions of rows I first conduct analysis on the first 1000 rows in which I create a hash table for each field and populate with the distinct values.
- For any field with more than 50 distinct values out of the 1000, I mark the field with a boolean flag HasHighDensityOfDistinctValues = true.
- For any such fields with HasHighDensityOfDistinctValues == true I create a separate text file and as I iterate through the main file, I write values for just that field out to the field-specific text file.
- For fields with a lower density of distinct values I maintain the hash table for each field and write distinct values to that.
- I noticed that in many of the high density fields, there are repeat values occurring (such as a PersonID) for multiple consecutive rows so, to reduce the number of entries to the field-specific text files, I store the previous value of the field and only write to the text file if the current value does not equal the previous value.  That cut down significantly on the total size of the field-specific text files.
- Once done iterating through the main file being processed, I iterate through my FieldProcessingResults class and for each field, if HasHighDensityOfDistinctValues==true, I read each line in the field-specific text file and populate the field-specific hash table with distinct values, then use HashTable.Count to determine the count of distinct values.
- Before moving on to the next field, I store the count associated with that field, then clear the hash table with myHashTable.Clear().  I close and delete the field-specific text file before moving on the the next field.

In this manner, I am able to get the count of distinct values for each field without necessarily having to concurrently populate and maintain an in-memory hash table for each field, which had caused the out of memory error.

Answer (score 0):

How many distinct values are you expecting? I used the following simple app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> ds = new Dictionary<string, int>;
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
            string s = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            d[s] = r.Next(0, 1000000);

            if (i % 100000 == 0)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Dict size: " + d.Count);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

together with .net 4.6.1, x64 build target I got to 40 million unique objects and 5.5 gigabytes of memory consumed before I ran out of memory on my machine (it's busy with other things at the moment, sorry)..

If you're going to be using arrays, you might nee an app.config that looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1"/>
    </startup>
    <runtime>
        <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true"/>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

You should be able to work out what sort of memory you'll need to track the distinct values and their counts. I recommend you work on one column at a time if you think it'll be in the hundreds of millions..

Just a minor clarification too: when i read "the number of distinct values" it makes me think you want to track the count of how many times each value appears. This is why I used `Dictionary<string, int>` - the string is the distinct value being counted and the int is the count

If you're looking to de-dupe a list of X million/billion values to just the distinct ones, with no need to count occurrences then HashSet might be lighter weight

Comment: Thank you for that.  I don't need a count of instances of each value, just the overall distinct count per field.  I am intrigued by the memory management techniques you suggest and I'll explore that.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do you consider getting a hash code of a value(assuming it cannot be larger than 128 bytes), creating a hash set and doing something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<object> vals = new List<object> {1, 'c', "as", 2, 1};

    foreach(var v in vals)
        Console.WriteLine($"Is uniques: {IsUniq(v)}");

    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static HashSet<object> _hashes = new HashSet<object>();
private static bool IsUniq(object v)
{
    return _hashes.Add(v);
}
```

It should be like 100-150 megabytes of raw data for 1 million elements.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried loading the file into a datatable and then doing your distinct selection via a dataview (not creating a copy)?
Check out

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fccda8dc-4515-4133-9022-2cb6bafa8ad9/how-does-a-dataview-act-in-memory?forum=netfxbcl

Here is some pseudo code

```
Read from File into Datatable
Create DataView with sort on the column you want
UniqueCount = 0
var CurrentValue="<some impossible value>"
For each ViewRow in DataView
    If CurrentValue <> ViewRow["MyColumn"]
        UniqueCount ++

UniqueCount should give me my result
```

This will be efficient because you are only using 2 variables UniqueCount and CurrentValue to loop through the data.
You are also sorting in dataview which does not make a copy of the data when processing.

Hope this helps